# C++ Vector Subscript Issues

Tags: c++, vector

I was making an app that calculates the mean, median, and range of any integers, but I ran into the issue: Vector subscript out of range. I've looked at some other posts about this, and still haven't been able to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Variables
    int sze;
    int mraw = 0;
    double mean;
    double median;
    double range;
    int fullnum = 0;
    int lastnum = 1;
    vector<int> med;

    cout << "How many numbers do you have?  ";
    cin >> sze;
    int *arr = new int[sze];
    for (int i = 0; i < sze; i++) {
        med.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    //Getting numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < sze, i++;) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Enter number #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    //Mean

    for (int i = 0; i < sze; i++){
        fullnum += arr[i];
    }
    mean = fullnum / sze;

    //Median

    sort(med.begin(), med.end());
    int mvs = sze;
    while (med.size() >= 2) {
        med.erase(med.begin());
        med.erase(med.begin() + med.size() - 1);
        mvs--;
    }
    if (mvs == 2) {
        mraw = med[1] + med[2];
        median = mraw / 2;
    }
    else {
         median = mvs;
    }

    //Range

    vector<int> rnge;
    for (int i = 0; i < sze; i++) {
        rnge.push_back(arr[i]);
        lastnum++;
    }
    sort(rnge.begin(), rnge.end());
    int bigsmall[2];
    bigsmall[1] = rnge[1];
    bigsmall[2] = rnge[lastnum];
    range = bigsmall[2] - bigsmall[1];

    //Outputs

    cout << "Mean: " << mean << "\nMedian: " << median << "\nRange: " << range;
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the issue highlighted in the answer below, you're not actually putting any meaningful values into your vector. You allocate the `arr` array and immediately copy its contents (which are uninitialized) into `med`, and then go on to read values into `arr`. You should get rid of `arr` altogether, and just use the vector.

Comment: What's the point of making `bigsmall` an array? Why not just use two variables, `int big, small`?

Comment: `arr` and `med` are completely separate. copying values from one to the other doesn't create a link

Answer (score 0):

You have what would be an [***off-by-one error***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) if `lastnum` was initialized to `0`.

When `rnge` is empty, presumably `lastnum` is `0`. This means access `rnge[lastnum]` is in error, as `rnge` is empty.

Applying an inductive argument shows that `lastnum` is the count of number of elements, and not the index of the last element. Thus, `rnge[lastnum]` is always out of range.

In actuality, you have initialized `lastnum` to `1`, so your bug is actually *off-by-two*.